# Sort command strange behaviour

Tags: sorting, awk, cat

Input file:  salary.txt

```
1 rob   hr 10000
2 charls it 20000
4 kk  Fin 30000
5 km  it 30000
6 kl  it 30000
7 mark  hr 10000
8 kc  it 30000
9 dc  fin 40000
10 mn  hr  40000
3 abi  it 20000
```

objective: find all record with second highest salary where 4rthcolumn is salary (space separated record)

I ran two similar commands but the output is entirely different, What is that I am missing?

Command1 :

```
sort -nr -k4,4 salary.txt | awk '!a[$4]{a[$4]=$4;t++}t==2'
```

output:

```
8 kc  it 30000
6 kl  it 30000
5 km  it 30000
4 kk  Fin 30000
```

command2:

```
 cat salary.txt | sort -nr -k4,4 | awk '!a[$4]{a[$4]=$4;t++}t==2'  salary.txt
```

output:

```
2 charls it 20000
```

the difference in the two commands is only the way salary.txt is read but why the output is entirely different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the second form `awk` will read directly from `salary.txt` - which you are passing as the name of the input file - ignoring the output from `sort` that you are passing to stdin. Leave out the final `salary.txt` in command2 and you'll see that the output matches that of command1. In fact, `sort` behaves the same way and the forms:

- `cat salary.txt | sort`
- `echo "string that will be ignored" | sort salary.txt`

will both yield the exact same output.

Answer (score 1):

In your second command does not, awk does not read from stdin. If you change it to

```
cat salary.txt | sort -nr -k4,4 | awk '!a[$4]{a[$4]=$4;t++}t==2'
```

you get the same result